# Rails - Rspec: Is it possible to exclude / remove a test case in a shared_example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hello everyone.

I have been working on a project and would like to use the shared example group to manage my RSpec test.

For instance, I have 2 actions in my controller.

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController 

   def show
      #...
   end

   def inspect 
      #...
   end
end
```

and a shared_example:

```rb
shared_examples "test" do 

  #...some examples

  it "raise an exception" do 
    # ... 
  end
end
```

However, when we call the "inspect", it will not raise an exception and result in test failure. Is it possible that I could disable or remove the test case temporary when I try to test for the "inspect" action? (in the real case, the shared examples have been used by many different tests and only one has different behavior.)

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to mark them as `broken` , i.e exclude the example based on a flag. See more info about that [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters).

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  # declare an exclusion filter
  c.filter_run_excluding :broken => true
end
```

try declare the configuration in a seperate context where you will test only the inspect so that the configuration does not affect others examples which also use the shared example you have.

For example:

```
 it "raise an exception", :broken => true do 
    # this spec will not run
  end
```

Comment: Alok, thank you very much. This is the right way to do.